# Using WireGuard on Raspberry Pi - NAT issue

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, vpn, nat

I try to run WireGuard with my Raspberry Pi 3B with Pi-OS but the NAT won‘t work.

When I start up the WireGuard I got this:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.10.10.1 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -6 route add ::/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -6 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -6 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

The iptables are looking as follows:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

But I can‘t connect from the wg0 10.10.10.2 to the 192.168.188.0/24 network. Do you have any ideas?

I'am able to connect to the 10.10.10.1/32 IP but I can't ping any device in the 192.168.188.0/24

Packet forwarding

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
#  based on Router Advertisements for this host
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

And the NAT as requested

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# iptables -t nat -vnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 49 packets, 14332 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 49 packets, 14332 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 490 packets, 32962 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 427 packets, 28720 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   63  4242 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

Output ip route

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ip route
default via 192.168.188.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.188.45 metric 202 
default via 192.168.188.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.188.20 metric 303 
192.168.188.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.188.45 metric 202 
192.168.188.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.188.20 metric 303
```

Output wg:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# wg
interface: wg0
  public key: Deleted
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820
  fwmark: 0xca6c

peer:deleted
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 80.142.204.XXX:62046
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
  transfer: 25.44 KiB received, 3.63 MiB sent
```

Updated for roaima: 12/24/2019

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sysctl -a | grep ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward_update_priority = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward_use_pmtu = 0

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sysctl -a | grep net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Comment: You should also show the nat table.

Comment: Hi Thomas is that what you‘re looking for?

Comment: This is also important. Do you have these forwards set? But I asked about `iptables -t nat -vnL`. Please update your question instead of posting comments.

Comment: Thanks - updated as requested

Comment: you should also give: the (main) routing table on both sides `ip route`. And the wg settings, as seen with `wg`. The important thing in `wg`'s output is `allowed ips`.

Comment: Updated as requested by A.B.

Comment: You've shown the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file but has kernel forward actually been applied (does `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` etc. tally with the information you've given us)?

Comment: The Pi is connected to your 192.168.188.0/24 network via its wired ethernet port (rather than wireless) isn't it...?

Comment: Yes bot network adapter are connected to the 192.168.188.0/24. And yes as shown in the main Topic (Update) the forward seems already applied to me.